# How can I make professional looking animations?

Tags: video, animation, 2d

I'm looking to make professional animations easily for a service I have. I'm wondering if it can be something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QRO3gKj3qw. Can this be done easily?

Comment: The best way to obtain a professional animation would be hiring a professional animator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For free, look at tools like [LiveSwif](http://www.liveswif.net/) or [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/). For paid, Adobe Flash is the benchmark. If you're a student, you can get Flash for under $200 from the Adobe Education Store

Answer (score 0):

If you have about 2,000 dollars to spare, invest in learning Adobe Flash.